# How do i set this as an async function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need to set this as an async function but im not sure how exacly, my first thought was to make it an async function in the Index.js by doing `client.on('message', async message => {` but even that doesnt work

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'meme',
    description: 'sends a random meme',
    execute(async, message, args, ) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const { Random } = require("something-random-on-discord")
        const random = new Random();
        var oneLinerJoke = require('one-liner-joke');
        var getRandomJoke = oneLinerJoke.getRandomJoke({
          'exclude_tags': ['dirty', 'racist', 'marriage']
         
        });
        let data = await random.getMeme()
        message.channel.send(data)

  
}
}
```

Comment: `async execute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate an async function by putting the `async` keyword to the definition like so:

```
async function execute(message, args) {
      const Discord = require('discord.js');
      const { Random } = require("something-random-on-discord")
      const random = new Random();
      var oneLinerJoke = require('one-liner-joke');
      var getRandomJoke = oneLinerJoke.getRandomJoke({
        'exclude_tags': ['dirty', 'racist', 'marriage']
      
      });
      let data = await random.getMeme()
      message.channel.send(data)
    }
    
    module.exports = {
      name: 'meme',
      description: 'sends a random meme',
      execute
    }
```